# How to clone a record and all of its nested relationships in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Trying to clone a record and all of its nested relationships and getting an error regarding one of the nested models on the `.Add` method:

> The instance of entity type {AnswerModel} cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

I'm assuming it has to do with some of the nested relationships. I tried setting this relationship (which is an `ICollection` denoting a many-to-many) to null, but then I just kept getting the same error on each relationship property until the error went away but then on creation almost none of the relationships were preserved (because I set them to null obviously). Any idea how to achieve this?

The service method

```
public AssessmentModel DuplicateAssessment (int ID)
{
     var assessment  = _assessmentRepository.GetByUniqueIDWithoutTracking(ID);
     assessment.ID = 0;
     assessment.Name = $"{assessment.Name} Duplicate";
     assessment.Description = $"Duplicated on {DateTime.Now}.{assessment.Description}";

     _assessmentRepository.DuplicateRecord(assessment);

     return assessment;              
}
```

The repo methods:

```
public AssessmentModel GetByUniqueIDWithoutTracking(int key)
{
        var response = new AssessmentModel();

        try
        {
            response = _compylDBContext.Assessments
                .Include(x => x.ControlSet)// has one
                .Include(x => x.AssessmentQuestions)//has many
                    .ThenInclude(q => q.AnswerSet)//has one
                        .ThenInclude(a => a.Answers)//has many
                .Include(x => x.AssessmentQuestions)
                    .ThenInclude(q => q.Control )//has one
                .Include( x => x.AssessmentQuestions)
                    .ThenInclude(q => q.Answers)//has many(so it's many to many)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == key);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

        return response;
}

public AssessmentModel DuplicateRecord(AssessmentModel AssessmentModel)
{
        AssessmentModel response;

        try
        {
            AssessmentModel.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
          
            foreach(var question in AssessmentModel.AssessmentQuestions)
            { 
                question.AssessmentID = 0;
                question.ID = 0; 
            }

            _compylDBContext.Add(AssessmentModel);
            _compylDBContext.SaveChanges();

            response = AssessmentModel;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

        return response;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: and you have to post Assessment class at least, but it is better if you post all included classes to see the relations. I am wondering if Accessment has required foreign keys columns. And I don't understand why do you need include statements in this case.

Comment: You need `.AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution` to ensure each `.Answers` with the same PK is the same object instance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution#identity-resolution-and-queries But you probably want to call `.TrackGraph` instead of `.Add` so you can be explicit about adding new instances.

Comment: Also if everything has the same `.Id` property, they should extend the same base type or implement the same interface so you can trivially clear it. Maybe implement some  `.ClearKeyColumns()` interface method to set all PK & FK properties to default values.

Comment: so some of the of the id's should change and some shouldn't. The new assessment and assessment questions should have new id's as they are the clones. Then for the relationship between answers and assessmentquestions; it is a join table with a composite key of anwerID and assessmentQuestionID so there should be new rows where the answer id is the same, but the question id reflects the new question. All other ID's should be the same.

Comment: Also after using .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution() - the error for the answermodel (and all the assessmentquestion reslatioships) is gone, but now I'm getting errors on other first level relationships (controlset)